# Quick Search - iOS

Tags: objective-c, search, nsregularexpression

I need to search an array of sentences for bad words. I have the functionality working, however, it is extremely slow:

```
for (int i=0; i<[badWords count]; i++)
{
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [badWords objectAtIndex:i];
    if ([text rangeOfString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\\b%@\\b", [dictionary objectForKey:@"word"]] options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch | NSRegularExpressionSearch].location != NSNotFound)
    {
        NSLog(@"Bad Word Found!");
    }
}
```

Is there a quicker way to do this? When I have a long list of words it takes awhile. Thanks!

Comment: Turn your `text` string into a dictionary with each word in the string as a key. Then you can check for many "bad words" just as fast as when you check for one.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Are you suggesting that I compare two dictionaries? Also, is there a way to keep the "\b" to check for blocks? For instance, I want the word "hell" to show up but not "hello".

Comment: @user3647894 can you please tell me about your sentences? or structure of the sentences.

Comment: @AmiriDev I am using this for a comment system. So the sentences may be anything from "Hello", "Hello!!!", "hell", "Hell!!!", " hell ", etc.

Comment: @user3647894 add me to skype amir.ios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing many regex searches, create a single huge regex pattern with every word and do just one search:

```
NSArray *words = @[@"foo", @"bar", ...];

NSRegularExpression *wordsExpression = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"\\b(%@)\\b", [keywords componentsJoinedByString:@"|"]] options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:NULL];

[keywordsExpression enumerateMatchesInString:string options:0 range:range usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *match, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop){
  // do something with match
}];
```

This is extremely fast in my tests (it finishes in thousands of a second), however I'm using it on an x86 processors. Perhaps the performance characteristics of an ARM processor are different since RegEx might not be as optimised for that architecture.

I'm using it here: https://github.com/abhibeckert/Dux/blob/master/Dux/DuxJavaScriptBaseElement.m

Comment: Is there a way to determine which word was found in the string? Thanks so much!

Comment: Of course. the `match` variable will tell you the range that was found, just grab the substring at that range.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use GCD will a little help for speed ...

```
dispatch_queue_t dqt = dispatch_queue_create("queue.concurrent",DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
    dispatch_apply([array count],dqt,^(size_t idx){
        NSDictionary *dictionary = [badWords objectAtIndex:idx];
        if ([text rangeOfString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\\b%@\\b", [dictionary objectForKey:@"word"]] options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch | NSRegularExpressionSearch].location != NSNotFound)
        {
             NSLog(@"Bad Word Found!");
        }
    }
});

dispatch_release(dqt);
```

but only a little ...